# JavaScript img.onerror changing source - race condition

Tags: javascript, image, onerror

The following code will register an onerror function for an image element

```
(function() {

    var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {   
        (function() {

                    imgElements[i].onerror = function() {
                        this.src = base_url() + 'assets/images/placeholder.jpg';
                    }


        })();
    }

})();
```

This code works only sometimes. (I'm using chrome); If i hold down F5 or refresh the page very fast, it seems like the onerror function does not get executed.

For example: If i load the page, then wait for a few seconds, and refresh again the src will change, but not all the time.

I believe this is some type of caching issue with the browser?

More specifically, If I press the refresh icon on chrome, everything will work, even on abrupt refreshes.

But, if I highlight the URL and press return, the code does not end up changing the src to my placeholder image.

Can you give me any insight into why this is happening, and suggest a way to circumvent this?

Comment: You're using `i`, but it's not a closure variable, so it will contain the last value from the loop.

Comment: I've changed it to pass in the object `imgElements[i]` and it is still resulting in the same functionality.

Comment: Actually, that's not relevant. You're not using `i` in the callback function. I don't understand why you have all those IIFEs in the first place, they're just making the code more confusing.

Comment: I removed the second IIFE

Comment: The only IIFE you need is the outer one, and that's just to keep `imgElements` from polluting the global namespace.

Comment: What errors are happening with your images that this code is supposed to react to?

Comment: An image elements src attribute gets replace, when I try to load a broken image (meaning the image source resulted in a 404). It's weird because when I directly write an onerror in html (e.g. `<img onerror=""`) this error goes away.

Comment: Try using `imageElements[i].addEventListener` instead of assigning to `.onerror`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot control the timing of things to make this work this way reliably the way you are trying to do it.   Here's the order things happen:

1. The browser fetches the HTML for the page
2. The browser starts parsing the HTML
3. As it finds an `<img>` tag, it fires off a request to load the `src` URL.
4. The browser discovers that the src URL cannot be loaded and thus fires the `onerror` handler.
5. Your javascript runs and installs `onerror` handlers.

Now, the order of steps 4 and 5 is purely timing related and is not under your control.  Some conditions may cause it to occur in this order and some conditions with 4 and 5 reversed.  And, keep in mind that once your page has been loaded once, parts of it may be cached and the timing sequence can be different in subsequent loads.  Some browsers may even cache the fact that a URL is currently unreachable and may avoid trying it again if it is immediately requests again (thus generating an immediate onerror response).

In addition, some browsers do not behave entirely properly when the `.src` property is set to a new value.  As of a couple years ago, I know that some browsers did not reliably fire the `onload` event when the `.src` propertyw was changed and a new image was loaded.  The same could be true for `onerror` handlers.  My experience is that they do work reliably for first time image loads, but I'm not sure they work reliably when setting a different `.src` property.

To have an onerror handler that will not be missed, you must have it in place before the `.src` property is set or parsed.  Here are two ways to do that.

1. Put the onerror handler in the HTML itself so it's part of the `<img>` tag.
2. Don't have fully formed `<img>` tags in your HTML (e.g. no .src or not in the HTML at all) and then with your javascript, you can add the onerror handler and THEN create the images or set the `.src` appropriately.

The key is that the `onerror` handler MUST be installed before the `.src` property is set in any way.

Solution #1 looks like this:

```
<img src="xxx.jpg" onerror="setErrorImage(this)">

// this function must be in the global scope
function setErrorImage(img) {
    // clear error handler so no chance of looping
    img.onerror = function() {};
    img.src = base_url() + 'assets/images/placeholder.jpg';
}
```

One way to implement solution #2 looks like this:

```
<img data-src="xxx.jpg">

(function() {
    function setErrorImage() {
        this.removeEventListener("error", setErrorImage);
        this.src = base_url() + 'assets/images/placeholder.jpg';
    }

    var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var img, url;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {   
        img = imgElements[i];
        // now that onerror handler is in place, set the .src property
        url = img.getAttribute("data-src")
        if (!img.src && url) {
            img.addEventListener("error", setErrorImage);
            img.src = url;
        }
    }
})();
```

You could also have no `<img>` tags in the HTML at all and create all of them dynamically via javascript, making sure that the onerror handlers were installed before the `.src` property was set, but this tends to make the design process a bit more complicated.  The above solution for option #2 is generally preferred over creating the image objects entirely in code.